# Adding to a select tag using document.forms

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>1</title>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="OnLoad()">
<form name="form">
    <select name="weapons" onChange="SelectWeapon()"></select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var weaponsArray = [
    'Broadsword',
    'Crossbow',
    'Magic staff'
];


function OnLoad() {
    for (var i = 0; i < weaponsArray.length; i++) {
        var wepType = "<option value = '" + i + "'>" + weaponsArray[i] + "</option>";
        document.forms["form"]["weapons"] += wepType;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the elements of the array to add to a select tag using document.forms by adding option tags to the array element and then adding it to the select tag.

I wanted this to end up populating a dropdown on a html page but the dropdown stays empty. I'm new to JavaScript so I am struggling to see where I have gone wrong.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? What do you get when you simply log `document.forms`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create an option, and then [Element.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to add it to the select element:

```js
var weaponsArray = [
    'Broadsword',
    'Crossbow',
    'Magic staff'
];

function OnLoad() {
    for (let i = 0; i <weaponsArray.length; i++) {
        
        // create a new option
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = i;
        option.textContent = weaponsArray[i];
        
        // add the option to the select element
        document.forms.form.weapons.append(option);
    }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="OnLoad()">
<form name="form">
    <select name="weapons"></select>
</form>
</body>
```